# Network subnets of class b private IP 172.16.0.0/20

Tags: networking, subnet

I am fairly new to networking i have a simple query on how I can work out the network, broadcast, first usable, last usable and the subnet mask for the IP in the title for 9 subnets.

Comment: Network classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1518 and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). Please let them rest in peace. Modern networking does not use network classes. See [this excellent answer](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7117/8499) for how to calculate IPv4 networks.

Comment: can you help me pls

Comment: I gave you a link for how to do that. It explains in detail what you need to do.

Comment: yh im fairly new to subnetting so id prefer someone actually helping my situation pls, if you cant then no problem

Comment: There is nothing anyone could add to that answer. It explains how to do everything you asked. What other help would you need?

Comment: so basically i have that ip address and i need to find the network, broadcast, first usable, last usable address for the 16 bits to accommodate for the 9 subnets in my situation

Comment: Right, and the answer I linked explains in detail how to do that.

Comment: how do i get the size of the subnet

Comment: to accommodate for the 200 hosts in my situation

Comment: Again, read the answer, it explains how to do that.

Comment: pls can you just help me, i have read it and got the addresses but i need to accommodate for the no. of hosts too in each subnet

Comment: As I wrote, I cannot add anything to that answer. I would tell you exactly the same thing. Just convert everything to binary, then it becomes obvious. do your calculations, then convert back to decimal. There really isn't anything more to it.

Comment: i needed help on subnettting based on host requirements

Comment: can you help me pls daniel

Comment: im really struggling here

Comment: The thread suggested by Daniel B seems to address what you're asking.  Can you clarify what isn't clear after reading that thread?  That will help people respond in a useful way.

Answer (score 0):

There are many online sites that provide tools to perform subnet calculations that you can find by searching on "subnet calculator" or "subnet calculator cidr". E.g., go to [CIDR / VLSM Supernet Calculator](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/cidr.php) and put 172.16.0.0 in the IP address field and then select 255.255.240.0, which corresponds to a /20, in the CIDR netmask field. Or, specifically for [172.16.0.0/20](http://jodies.de/ipcalc?host=172.16.0.0&mask1=20&mask2=) at [IP Calculator](http://jodies.de/ipcalc). There are also online courses that will teach you how to perform such calculations yourself, e.g., Udemy offers [Subnetting Made Super Simple](https://www.udemy.com/super-simple-subnetting/) (current cost $15 [USD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USD)) and [other courses on the topic](https://www.udemy.com/courses/search/?q=subnetting&src=sac&kw=subnet).

Comment: i need help on subentting based on hosts

Comment: for each subnet, each sybnet hs different number oif hosts

Comment: You put "172.16.0.0/20" in the subject of your message, which gives you up to 4,096 subnets. Of course, if you only need 9 subnets, that's far more than you need. What difference does it make to you if one subnet actually has more IP addresses allocated to hosts in that subnet than another?

Comment: @moonpoint, why do you say, "_gives you up to 4,096 subnets_?" If you use `/21` subnets, then you only have two subnets, or if you use `/31` subnets, then you can have 2048 subnets. The 4096 number is actually the number of hosts in a `/20` network.

Comment: i need to find network address broadcast address and the usable range for each subnet

Comment: BUT each subnet has differenet number of hosts

Comment: this is where im struggling

Comment: get the addresses for different number of hosts in each subnet

Comment: @Ron Maupin It was an error; thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Sam, the link I provided you spells out how to do everything you are asking. There is even a section titled **Finding the required subnet masklength or netmask** that tells you how to determine the required size for the number of hosts. What is your problem with it, or are you simply wanting someone to do your work for you, even though you asked how?

Comment: i didnt read that title, i thought it meant something different, ill read it now

Comment: @Sam, if you want to know how to do this stuff, you need to read and understand the entire answer. It is all inter-related. It explains everything you need to know about calculating IPv4 networks.